# Symbolic breakpoints in Swift

Tags: swift, lldb

**Is it possible to set symbolic breakpoints in Swift for swift based code?**

Let's say I have a class like

```
class AwesomeSauce {

    var ingredients: [String]

    init(useIngredients:[String]) {
        ingredients = useIngredients
    }
}
```

And let's say the `ingredients` array is sorted like

```
var specialSauce = AwesomeSauce(["Sugar","Spice","Everything Nice", "Chemical 'X'"])

specialSauce.ingredients.sort({ $0.length() > $1.length() })
```

Let's also say (because I'm not paying attention) that I sort this array in a bunch of different places throughout my project.

I want to see when `ingredients` is being sorted.

#### Is there a way I can set a symbolic breakpoint on `Array.sort()` or `AwesomeSauce.ingredients.sort()` or something like that?

I can't seem to get anything to work and I've tried various permutations of possible symbols.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are adding the "()".  If you add argument specifiers lldb will take you seriously, and there isn't an Swift.Array.sort that takes no arguments.  Unless you really need to break on one overload of a function, it's much easier to just give the function identifier w/o the arguments.  In fact, even if you want to break on an overload it's easier to break on the name and then disable all the locations except the overload you want, since getting the parameters exactly right is often a pain...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a symbolic breakpoint on `Swift.Array.sort` should do the trick.

Here is a sample session from the command-line with swiftc and lldb,
but you can do the same within Xcode:

```
$ xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc -g main.swift 

$ lldb main

(lldb) target create "main"
Current executable set to 'main' (x86_64).

(lldb) b main
Breakpoint 1: where = main`main + 106 at main.swift:13, address = 0x0000000100001aea

(lldb) run
Process 8032 launched: './main' (x86_64)
7 locations added to breakpoint 1
1 location added to breakpoint 1
4 locations added to breakpoint 1
Process 8032 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c46ff, 0x0000000100001aea main`main + 106 at main.swift:13, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001aea main`main + 106 at main.swift:13
   10       }
   11   }
   12   
-> 13   var specialSauce = AwesomeSauce(useIngredients: ["Sugar","Spice","Everything Nice", "Chemical 'X'"])
   14   
   15   specialSauce.ingredients.sort( { count($0) > count($1) })
   16   

(lldb) b Swift.Array.sort
Breakpoint 2: where = libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> (), address = 0x0000000100030160

(lldb) c
Process 8032 resuming
Process 8032 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c46ff, 0x0000000100030160 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> (), queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100030160 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> ()
libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> ():
->  0x100030160 : pushq  %rbp
    0x100030161 : movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100030164 : pushq  %r15
    0x100030166 : pushq  %r14

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c46ff, 0x0000000100030160 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> (), queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 2.1
  * frame #0: 0x0000000100030160 libswiftCore.dylib`Swift.Array.sort (inout Swift.Array)((A, A) -> Swift.Bool) -> ()
    frame #1: 0x0000000100001c99 main`main + 537 at main.swift:15
    frame #2: 0x00007fff8cff65c9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: It *doesn't* work in Swift 4 for `Swift.Array.sort`. It *does* work for `Swift.Array.popLast` though.

Comment: After trying numerous various variants I found only `.sort` works in Xcode 9